# How to list applied migrations from command line?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I had run makemigrations and after that migrate to apply the migration

```
python manage.py showmigrations
admin
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_logentry_remove_auto_add
auth
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_alter_permission_name_max_length
 [X] 0003_alter_user_email_max_length
 [X] 0004_alter_user_username_opts
 [X] 0005_alter_user_last_login_null
 [X] 0006_require_contenttypes_0002
 [X] 0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages
 [X] 0008_alter_user_username_max_length
 [X] 0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length
boards
 [X] 0001_initial
contenttypes
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_remove_content_type_name
sessions
 [X] 0001_initial
```

How to find out models in boards from command line?

Comment: Not even close to a duplicate.

Comment: Do you mean which models are created/altered as part of each migraiton file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll need to use some undocumented APIs for this, but here's one way:

```
from django.db import connections
from django.db.migrations.loader import MigrationLoader

loader = MigrationLoader(connections['default'])
loader.load_disk()
```

After this, `loader.disk_migrations` will be a dictionary whose keys are `(app_name, migration_name)` tuples, and whose values are the `Migration` objects. So iterating `loader.disk_migrations.keys()` will give you a list close to what you want, and you can just format it as desired.

If you want only the ones that have been applied:

```
from django.db.migrations.recorder import MigrationRecorder
recorder = MigrationRecorder(connections['default'])
```

And then access `recorder.applied_migrations()`

If you want to learn a lot about how migrations work internally, and how Django figures out what migrations you have and which are applied, check out [the source code of the `manage.py migrate` command](https://github.com/django/django/blob/10b44e45256ddda4258ae032b8d4725a3e3284e6/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py#L1).